# Number value wrong in event bound through a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, alert

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        $(rows[i]).click(function () {
            alert('I am line number ' + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, 
how would I get actual  line number for each row ? since all I get when I trigger click event on an even row, upper bound value is alerted (i.e: rows.length = 7, `i` would be 6 for each row clicked).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that upon `click` event is triggered, the `i` variable was already changed by the loop iteration. *Theoretically* you can use closure to make things working, i.e.

```
for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        (function(i) {
            $(rows[i]).click(function() {
                alert("I am line number " + i);
            });
        )(i);
    }
}
```

*Practically*, if you use jQuery (as I understood from the code), it is easier to use [`:even`](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector:

```
$(".row:even").click(function() {
    alert("I am line number " + $(".row").index(this));
});
```

Comment: AH you beat me to it! Good answer.

Comment: NB: `.index()` is `O(n)`, not `O(1)`.  Also, it'll only work as expected if all the elements are children of the same parent.

Comment: @Alnitak Yup. This is just example of how to get index of it. If there is a speed constraint, pure JS with one `for` loop will do the job perfectly. **UPD:** now the index will be calculated fine.

Comment: FYI, the first code example here is missing a closing curly bracket to close "(function(i) {"

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting the wrong number is that the event handler functions you're creating get an *enduring reference* to the `i` variable, *not* a copy of it as of when they're created.

The way to solve it is to have the handler close over something that *won't* change. Here are three ways to do that, the first is specific to jQuery (it looks like you're using jQuery):

### jQuery's `each`

It looks like you're using jQuery, in which case you can use its `each` to get an index to use that won't change:

```
var rows = $(".row");
rows.each(function(index) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            alert('I am line number ' + index);
        });
    }
});
```

Now, the event handler function closes over the `index` argument of the call to the function we give `each`, and since that `index` argument never changes, you see the right number in the alert.

### Use a builder function

(Non-jQuery) You can solve this with a builder function:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        $(rows[i]).click(buildHandler(i));
    }
}
function buildHandler(index) {
    return function () {
        alert('I am line number ' + index);
    };
}
```

Here,  the event handler function closes over the `index` argument in `buildHandler`, and since that `index` argument never changes, you see the right number in the alert.

### `forEach`

(Non-jQuery) You can also use ES5's `forEach` function (which is one of the ES5 features you can shim on a pre-ES5 environment) to solve this:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(rows, function(row, index) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
        $(row).click(function () {
            alert('I am line number ' + index);
        });
    }
});
```

This works the same way as the two above, by closing over `index`, which doesn't change.

Comment: @Alnitak: Not necessarily. That could be any of several other minor libraries that use `$` and provide a `click`. I'll be it **is** jQuery, but that doesn't mean it is. (And the other options will be useful for people finding this if it happens *they* don't use jQuery. The fools.)

Comment: @Alnitak: All three of them are closure-based answers.